# pose estimation of 3d object in video

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, computer-vision, augmented-reality

I am trying to do depth estimation on the video stream of a camera. I am actually only interested in the depth of one single object shown in the video stream. 
What would be the simplest way to achieve this?

I have the camera pose available, so the first idea was to get corner features from the object, track them, and triangulate them. But this is a lot of effort...

A second idea was doing something like marker tracking (like the Aruco markers), but the object has a very inconsistent non-flat surface, so this would be too difficult.

Third idea was to get some reference lengths on the object that I can physically measure, get the same lengths in the image and estimate the depth through this. But as far as I understand this would result in problems with perspectives.

I have openCV available and I'm programing in C#/C++

Comment: Humans have two eyes to pervice depth. Therefore easiest way is to have (at least 2) cameras. Or a camera(s) and projector(s) a.k.a structured light. I was making some depth maps using that last one technology, I can recommend the following article if you are interested: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6375029.

Comment: thanks, the article is interesting, but unfortunately I don't have that available